# Pass an enum value from lightning controller to Apex

Tags: apex, lightning, parameters, enum

Is it possible to pass an enum value from lightning controller to Apex?

Here is what I tried

**lightning component part**

```
    const action = component.get("methodC");
    action.setParams({p: "VIEW"});
    action.setCallback(component, function(){});
    $A.getCallback(function(){$A.enqueueAction(action);})();
```

**apex part**

```
public enum Mode { CREATE, VIEW, EDIT }

@AuraEnabled
public static void methodC(Mode p) {
    System.debug('p:' + p);
}
```

And here is the error I am getting:

> 16:35:58:002 FATAL_ERROR System.JSONException: Illegal value for primitive

[image]

Would be grateful for any relevant documentation on the topic. [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_enums.htm) is what I was able to find, but it is of no use for my question about lightning client-side and Apex enum.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The types that can be passed are limited, leaving you to have to do more work than ideal sometimes.

In this case, code like this should work:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void methodC(String p) {
    Mode pMode = toMode(p);
    ...
}

private static Mode toMode(String s) {
    for (Mode m : Mode.values()) {
        if (m.name() == s) return m;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: if you try returning enum value back from Apex to lightning controller it returns blank object as well.

Comment: I'd suggest that if toMode doesn't find an appropriate enumeration value, then that should be an exception rather than a null.

Bear in mind, if you *could* pass enumerations, then an invalid value would probably be a compile error.

Remember: Friends don't let friends return null.